# javascript in jquery popup

Tags: javascript

Am trying to pass a argument in jquery html pop up.But am not able
        to do so.The below is my code.

```
var emailid =result.rows[0].emailid;
        var html =                     '<input type="button" class="closebtn" value="close"/>' 
                                           + 'Firstname  :'+result.rows[0].firstname+'<br/>'
                                           + 'Lastname   :'+result.rows[0].lastname+'<br/>'
                                           + 'Emailid    :'+result.rows[0].emailid+'<br/>'
                                           +'<input type="button"  value="Approve"                        
    onClick="approve('emailid');"/>;



  JAVASCRIPT is
             function approve(id){   
              var email=id;    
              alert(email);  
          }
```

1. It says missing something in my variable html.I tried passing like

   ```
       `onClick="approve(emailid);".`
   ```

   Even it doesnt work.Can you please pointout wat error am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var html =  '<input type="button" class="closebtn" value="close"/>' 
             + 'Firstname  :'+result.rows[0].firstname+'<br/>'
             + 'Lastname   :'+result.rows[0].lastname+'<br/>'
             + 'Emailid    :'+result.rows[0].emailid+'<br/>'
             +'<input type="button"  value="Approve" onClick="approve(\'emailid\');"/>';
```

The problem was having quotes inside of quotes. You need to escape them with backslashes.

Edit. Or... you probably meant:

```
var html =  '<input type="button" class="closebtn" value="close"/>' 
             + 'Firstname  :'+result.rows[0].firstname+'<br/>'
             + 'Lastname   :'+result.rows[0].lastname+'<br/>'
             + 'Emailid    :'+result.rows[0].emailid+'<br/>'
             +'<input type="button"  value="Approve" onClick="approve(\'' + emailid + '\');"/>';
```

Here's a quick and dirty demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SwhWx/3/

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But  onClick="approve(\'emailid\');" just gives emailid not the value and the second one doesnt work at all.I don know what to do.

Comment: Can I know y did u give this line in the fiddle?                                                   document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = html;​

Comment: @Idsaru Try `onClick="approve(\'' + emailid + '\');"`. The reason I did `innerHTML = html` was to output the variable in to the DOM to test that it works

Comment: @Idsaru It's customary to Accept (and optionally up-vote) the correct answer

Comment: @Idsaru you mark it as useful by clicking the ^ arrow, and click the tick to accept the answer